# List channels doesn't give when the channel was created in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Hi I want to find out when the channel is created for polling purpose I want this data means depending on the creation time I can find out whether new channel is created in Microsoft Teams if yes which it is.I checked with the graph api but it doesn't gives me the information like creation time of channel.

Comment: Are you looking at notifications when new channel is created? If yes, currently notifications api's are not in place. They are in development but can not provide timelines.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Can we use polling mechanism but response data done't contain when actually the channel is created means creation time of the channel is not present.

Comment: Currently there is no way to find out the creation time of the channel. Probably in future notification api's will come handy to handle this situation.